# How do create a 3 color column without text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a 3 color column with bootstrap without text.

I've created the columns with the colors I wanted selected, however how can I remove the text without losing the column? When I removed the text directly the columns shrunk.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#ACE0F8;">.col-sm- 
4</div>
<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#9487BF;">.col-sm- 
4</div>
<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#5C7795;">.col-sm- 
4</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: try giving height  property. what version of bootstrap you are using ? may be i can create you snippet. Something like height: 20px or 100px

Comment: @danny I'm using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS.

Add some classes, then style them.

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 !important; /* because it renders off screen w bootstrap */
}

.row .ccol {
  min-height: 16px;
}

.c1 {
  background: #ACE0F8;
}

.c2 {
  background: #9487BF;
}

.c3 {
  background: #5C7795;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 ccol c1"></div>
  <div class="col-4 ccol c2"></div>
  <div class="col-4 ccol c3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`col-xs-4` is not a valid bootstrap 4 class, these are the valid classes:

1. .col-
2. .col-sm-
3. .col-md-
4. .col-lg-
5. .col-xl-

Also, you need to give the empty column, a min height for it to appear.

```css
/* you need to give your columns some height, so they appear */
.row div {
  height: 30px;
}

/*it's better not to use inline css and put your colors in a css file */
.my-col-1 {
  background-color: #ACE0F8;
}

.my-col-2 {
  background-color: #9487BF;
}

.my-col-3 {
  background-color: #5C7795;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 my-col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-4 my-col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-4 my-col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 c" style="background-color:#ACE0F8;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 c" style="background-color:#9487BF;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 c" style="background-color:#5C7795;"></div>
</div>
```

Added another css class so you don't have to messed up current class.

```
.row{
  margin: 0;
}

.row .c{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Also there is no such classes in Bootstrap 4 buddy. 
Reference Link: [Bootstrap 4 Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)